# MySQL trigger concat with curdate()

Tags: mysql, triggers

i need a help to format this trigger output.

I need the output of the trigger have this format:

```
2013/0001
2013/0002
...
```

When year changes,

```
2014/0001
2014/0002
...
```

but my trigger generates that format:

```
00012013/
```

The trigger code is below:

```
SET NEW.num = CONCAT(
LPAD(COALESCE(
  (SELECT MAX(LEFT(num, 4)) 
     FROM `tb_numeros`
    WHERE num LIKE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y/____')), 0) + 1, 4, '0'), 
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y/'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indentation to clarify what's going on:

```
SET NEW.num = CONCAT(
    LPAD(
        COALESCE(
            (
                SELECT MAX(LEFT(num, 4)) 
                FROM `tb_numeros`
                WHERE num LIKE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y/____')
            ), 0
        ) + 1, 4, '0'
    ), 
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y/')
)
```

It's clear that you get year on second place because, well, it's the second clause inside `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Im trying change order, but generates mysql error.
Any sugestion about his order?

Comment: How could I suggest anything? I don't know how you changed the code or what error you get now.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand how you get the number sequence, however, I think you can simplify the code a bit:

```sql
...
SET `get_year` := YEAR(NOW());
SET `sequence` := (SELECT... WHERE... `num`... LIKE... `get_year`...); /* RETURN 0001 */
SET NEW.`num` := CONCAT(`get_year`, '/', `sequence`);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah! woRKS!!!

```
SET NEW.num = CONCAT(
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y/'),
LPAD(
    COALESCE(
        (
            SELECT MAX(RIGHT(num, 4)) 
            FROM `tb_numeros`
            WHERE num LIKE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y/____')
        ), 0
    ) + 1, 4, '0'
)
)
```